# How and where to use JmsListenerEndpointRegistry start and stop function using SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to stop/pause the queue so that (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5229)

1. NO messages sent to the associate consumers
2. messages still to be enqueued on the queue
3. ability to be able to browse the queue
4. all the JMX counters for the queue to be available and correct.

**Added:** *Apache ActiveMQ (Version 5.16.2)*

But I don't know where to create the bean of JmsListenerEndpointRegistry and call start and stop method.
**Sample code will be appreciated. Thanks.**

Comment: I am using Apache ActiveMQ (Version 5.16.2), please help me if you can. thanks

Comment: The queue "pause" functionality in ActiveMQ has *nothing* to do with anything in Spring's `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry`. However, you seem to be conflating two. Can you elaborate on your use-case. Which bit of functionality do you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` is automatically configured by Spring Boot.

Simply `@Autowired` it into the controlling class, give the `JmsListener` an `id` and stop/start it using the id.

Note: this does not use the AMQ feature you referenced; it simply tells the listener container to stop/start receiving messages.